# Select and update statments in CASE statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables.

Main_Table

`SUB_ID SUB_ADDR_ID
47587   254875
47859   524858
47950   651681
47582   315788
54495   254879`

Sub_master

`SUB_NAME   SUB_ID  SUB_ADDR_ID     PRIMARY
  ABC       47587     254875           Y

  ABC       47857     254876           N

  CDE       47858     256587           Y

  EFG       47859     524584           Y

  EFG       47859     524858           N

  GHI       54495     255485           Y

  GHI      54495      254879           N`

I have to select all records from the first table, compare the `SUB_ADDR_ID` with the `sub_master` table to check weather the updated value is primary or not. If not primary, I have to update the primary value in the main table. how to achieve this in single query.

Comment: Update the primary value to what?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the filtering in a `where` clause.  Here is an example using `exists`:

```
update main_table mt
    set <col> = <value>
    where exists (select 1
                  from sub_master sm
                  where sm.sub_id = mt.sub_addr_id and
                        primary <> 'Y'
                 );
```

Comment: what is that <value> you are talking about?

Comment: The `set` clause is whatever you want to set in the first table.  Your question was not clear on either the column name or the value.

Comment: I want to set `SUB_ADDR_ID`. For some records, `SUB_ADDR_ID` is populated wrong. So I have to fetch the correct `SUB_ADDR_ID` according to the `Primary` values. ie. I have to update `SUB_ADDR_ID` which has the `Primary` as ''Y''